# How to know if file is renamed or new file in github PR

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I am a newbie to github code review process. When i was reviewing code i came across a file that had all the code repeated from another file with minor changes , so i wondered if the class was renamed to a new one or if a new file was created.

I later figured it out that it is a new file by checking that the old file still exists in the branch created by the reviewee.

But just wondering if there is a straightforward way to know in the pull request in github if a file is new file or had been renamed?

Answer (score 2):

If a file was renamed in a Pull Request, you will be able to tell in several ways:

1. The message `File renamed without changes` will appear under that file's diff in the Pull Request GUI
2. The file diff header will be [old file path] → [new file path]
3. The number of changed lines will always be zero.

[image: github file diff for renamed file]